# Redirect to value url on select submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to redirect the user to the URL specified in the select value. For styling to the select I had to go a custom route hence the way its set-up. Am I approaching it wrong, if so what is the most efficient way to approach it?

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <span class="dropdown-el" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="Relevance" checked="checked" id="services">
         <label for="services">Select one ...</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-best"><label for="sort-best">Option 1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-low"><label for="sort-low">Option 2</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-high"><label for="sort-high">Option 3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-brand"><label for="sort-brand">Option 4</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-name"><label for="sort-name">Option 5</label>
     </span>
     <button type="submit" class="hero-form-btn" onClick="WinOpen();">Go &#8594;</button>
 </form>
```

**Jquery/JavaScript**

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('span').on('change', function() {
            var url = $(this).val();

            if (url) {
                window.location = url;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've looked through it so many times that I'm beginning to get lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `<a>` tags instead?

Comment: Because of the functionality i was looking to achieve. I want the user to select from the drop down and submit it to redirect them to another page based on their selection.

Comment: What is the purpose of submitting and what actually happens besides redirecting the user? If you are using php to handle the submit, you can set the `heaer (Location URL)` to point to the chosen value... if it just for redirect i would use plain 'a' for that...

Answer (score 0):

You should take the value from the selected radio button:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('span').on('change', function(val) {

        var url = $("input[name='services']:checked").val();

        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can test it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6k8cnxhp/

Comment: This works in your fiddle for the most part but doesn't act similarly one the site. When I hit submit, it just refreshes the page and appends "?services=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com" to the url

Comment: you could use window.open(url); if you want to have it in a different tab.

Comment: For some reason it's not opening anything in a new tab.

Comment: Sorry without any more information it would be hard to help you.

Comment: I've included a jfiddle of what im experiencing: https://jsfiddle.net/rc6m9owt/2/

Comment: You have some issue with your selector, it doesn't get the changes of your radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Your button is in the form tag with a type="submit". Submit adds http://yoursite.com?yourQueryToServer the query string to your URL to be sent to the server.

If you want to leave the button in the form tag, change the type="button"

Try this.

I didn't quite understand why you have a submit button, but you reload onChange, so I changed that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <span class="dropdown-el" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="Relevance" checked="checked" id="services">
            <label for="services">Select one ...</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-best"><label
                for="sort-best">Option 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-low"><label for="sort-low">Option
                2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-high"><label
                for="sort-high">Option 3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-brand"><label
                for="sort-brand">Option 4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-name"><label
                for="sort-name">Option 5</label>
        </span>
        <button type="button" class="hero-form-btn" onClick="WinOpen();">Go &#8594;</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $('span').on('change', function (val) {

            let url = $("input[name='services']:checked").val();

            if (url) {
                window.location = url;
            }
        });
        function changePage() {
            window.location = url;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

or with reloading onChange

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <span class="dropdown-el" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="Relevance" checked="checked" id="services">
            <label for="services">Select one ...</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-best"><label
                for="sort-best">Option 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-low"><label for="sort-low">Option
                2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-high"><label
                for="sort-high">Option 3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-brand"><label
                for="sort-brand">Option 4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-name"><label
                for="sort-name">Option 5</label>
        </span>
        <button type="button" class="hero-form-btn" onClick="WinOpen();">Go &#8594;</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var url = null

        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('span').on('change', function (val) {

                var url = $("input[name='services']:checked").val();

                if (url) {
                    window.location = url;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        function changePage() {
            window.location = url;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This didnt appear to fix it either :(

Comment: Try to copy this and run it in a new index.html. If it doesn't work the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of submitting and what actually happens besides redirecting the user? 
If it just for redirect, change the button type to button instead of submit since  when you hit submit you refresh the page and any code assign to the function (winOpen) won't be execute...

If you don't need to actually submit the form, your code can be something like that:

```js
let url = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="services"]');
for (let i=0; i < url.length; i++) {
  url[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('form > button')[0].setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.assign("'+url[i].value+'")');
  });
};
```

```html
<form>
    <span class="dropdown-el" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="Relevance" checked="checked" id="services">
         <label for="services">Select one ...</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.google.com" id="sort-best"><label for="sort-best">Option 1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.microsoft.com" id="sort-low"><label for="sort-low">Option 2</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.stackoverflow.com" id="sort-high"><label for="sort-high">Option 3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.mdn.com" id="sort-brand"><label for="sort-brand">Option 4</label>
         <input type="radio" name="services" value="http://www.cnn.com" id="sort-name"><label for="sort-name">Option 5</label>
     </span>
     <button type="button" class="hero-form-btn">Go &#8594;</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
o button click option place windowlocation.href   I modify the code  <script>
        var url = null
 
        jQuery(function ($) {
           // $('span').on('change', function (val) {
  $('.hero-form-btn').on('click',function(e){
                var url = $("input[name='services']:checked").val();

                if (url) {
      window.document.location.href = url; 
                    //window.location = url;
                }
  //});
                return false;
            });
        });
        function changePage() {
            window.location = url;
        }
    </script>
```